# Why is there an error with the package csquotes in this context?

Tags: csquotes

I have a problem when I use the command enquote of the package csquotes (style=spanish) and the bibliographystyle caauda0.bst.
I give you a MWE to illustrate, but I get the following error:

```
    LaTeX Error: Command \enquote already defined.
    
     
    ‪./output.bbl, 6‬
    Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
    
    See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
    Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
     ...                                              
                                                      
    l.6 ...nquote}[1]{\guillemotleft#1\guillemotright}
                                                      
    Your command was ignored.
    Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
    or  <return>  to continue without it.
```

Do you understand why this happens? I need to use XeLatex to compile.

MWE:

```
     \documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[catalan]{babel}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[style=spanish]{csquotes}

\begin{filecontents}{\bib.bib}
@book{key,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}
    
    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{BON DIA}
    
    \enquote{Aquest títol}. 
\cite{key}



   
\end{frame}
  \begin{frame}{BON DIA}
\bibliography{bib}
\bibliographystyle{caauda0}        
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

It seems that the problem is with the bibliography style:
https://ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/catalan

Comment: your example gives no error in xelatex from texlive 2023

Comment: show your full log (as a text block not a quote, so line endings are preserved)

Comment: I only det a warning that `catalan` is not a known language to `csquotes`

Comment: You only show a fragment of the error but it shows that some file that you have not shown has a definition of `\enquote` on line 6 that is an error as (presumably) it is already defined by the csquotes package.

Comment: Note this is an error, not a warning.

Comment: Yes. It is not a warning. I edit the question.

Comment: I have no error here, but wrong quotes. I think you should read page 3 (table 1) of the manual and choose (or configure) a quotation style (I do not know the Catalan styles...)

Comment: More importantly fix the question so the example is an example of your problem. there is no point posting an unrelated document that does not have the problem you are asking about.

Comment: It gives me error with the other document, not with the MWE.

Comment: In this case the shown code is not a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) of the issue but useless.

Comment: OK. I will try to fix it later.

Comment: You should put here a document showing the error. Otherwise, the problem is impossible to debug (can't you see that?). Take you failing document and minimize it, then post that. (BTW, I edited your post to show the usage of triple ticks to mark the code, it's handier for long snippets than indenting)

Comment: You have added a lot of unrelated packages so it takes longer to run and is harder to trace, but still is not an example ofyour problem.

Comment: "It gives me error with the other document, not with the MWE."  The E in MWE stands for example. It is supposed to be an example of your problem, otherwise there is no point in including it, it just confuses people trying to help. The M means it should be minimal,so  don't include tikz (which you just added) unless you are showing that the problem only happens if you include tikz.

Comment: you get the error on line 6 of a file you have not shown that has `\newcommand\enquote` (you could avoid the error by using `\renewcommand` but then you are over-writing all the features of the `csquotes` package)

Comment: Does the problem maybe only occur in documents with a bibliography?

Comment: Why do you load this twice? `\usepackage{linguex}`

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz oh well spotted yes.  crealp the error is in your bibliography.

Comment: Yes! I update the question. Sorry for the delay. I had class.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks. I was including everything because I had no clue about which package was causing the problem. I think I have solved the problem now. (Hopefully!) Sorry for the mess.

Comment: https://ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/catalan

Comment: Do you have to use this style? For some reasons it thinks that defining `\enquote` would be a good idea ...

Comment: Is there a way to change the bst file to avoid this problem?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please extend your code to a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407).

Comment: Why was this closed long after the OP added the necessary details? I'm voting to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bst file has

```
"\newcommand{\enquote}[1]{\guillemotleft#1\guillemotright}"
```

which is a bit unfortunate, but a simple fix is to change a local copy of that to

```
"\renewcommand{\enquote}[1]{\guillemotleft#1\guillemotright}"
```